# svg translate option is not working for g when defined in css

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to translate `g#node` using CSS

```css
#node{
    transform: translate(200, 50);
}
```

```html
<svg id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="node">
        <rect width="104" height="27" rx="15" ry="15" id="node-2" transform="translate(30, 50)" ></rect>
        <rect width="104" height="20" rx="15" ry="15" id="node-1" transform="translate(10, 20)" ></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

But the translate option is not working from CSS. But if I replace `translate()` with `scale(2)` everything is working.
Also when I set translate inside `<g>` element everything is working too.

How I can set translate from CSS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is associated with the translation unit. You need to explicitly mention that unit is `px` or what ever it is.

```css
#node {
  transform: translate(200px, 50px);
}
```

```html
<svg id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="node">
    <rect width="104" height="27" rx="15" ry="15" id="node-2" transform="translate(30, 50)"></rect>
    <rect width="104" height="20" rx="15" ry="15" id="node-1" transform="translate(10, 20)"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the [SVG transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform). The CSS variant is limited for SVG.

[This article (CSS-TRICKS: SVG Animation and CSS Transforms: A Complicated Love Story)](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/) and [this (CSS-TRICKS: Transforms on SVG Elements)](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/) is maybe also interesting.